# Is this identity correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Is this identity true? Wolfram|Alpha [thinks is not](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%28ln%28x%5E3%29%29+%3D+e%5E%283*%28ln%28x%29%5E2%29%29).

## $$x^{ln(x^3)} = e^{3\,[ln(x)]^2}$$

That's how I demonstrated it:

## $${\left(e^{ln(x)}\right)}^{3\,ln(x)} = e^{3\,[ln(x)]^2}$$

## $$e^{3\,ln(x)\,ln(x)} = e^{3\,[ln(x)]^2}$$

## $$e^{3\,[ln(x)]^2} = e^{3\,[ln(x)]^2}$$

Comment: on the contrary it does (for x>0) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%28ln%28x%5E3%29%29-+e%5E%283*%28ln%28x%29%5E2%29%29

Comment: To test if two expressions are equal in something like wolfram alpha, I find it best to take one side of the expression and subtract the other side.  Wolfram does in fact spit out that it thinks they are equal on the condition that $x>0$.  In the case that $x$ is some other complex number, then its not necessarily true.  http://tinyurl.com/ol6p5er

Answer (score 3):

taking the logarithm of both sides we obtain $\ln(x^3)\ln(x)=3\ln(x)^2$ and the right hand side is $3\ln(x)^2\ln(e)=3\ln(x)^2$  thus the equation
$x^{\ln(x^3)}=e^{3\ln(x)^2}$ is true for $x>0$.